# Count determined word with many IDs in text column using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, count, cpu-word

This question is about MySQL Query. I have three tables:

1.brand (consists of: text)

2.englishkeyword (consists of ID, word)

3.englishmodel (consists of: ID, Pscore)

I want to count how many words in 'text' with the word which is already determined in 'word'. Then the result is stored in 'Pscore'. This is my code

```
UPDATE englishmodel 
SET Pscore=( SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM brand 
            WHERE text LIKE CONCAT('%', (SELECT word 
                                         FROM englishkeyword 
                                         WHERE ID=1), '%')
          ) 
WHERE ID=1;
```

And it works. 
My question is: Could I do this query for many ID in a time? let say I have 1000 ID.

Then I edit like this way:

```
SELECT ek.ID as ID, COUNT(*) as Pscore
FROM englishkeyword ek, brand
WHERE (brand.text LIKE CONCAT('%', ek.word, '%'))
GROUP BY ek.ID;

INSERT INTO englishmodel (ID, Pscore)
    SELECT ek.ID as ID, COUNT(*) as Pscore
    FROM englishkeyword ek, brand
    WHERE (brand.text LIKE CONCAT('%', ek.word, '%'))
    GROUP BY ek.ID
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE Pscore = VALUES(Pscore)
```

But the result is like this:

[image]

Sincerely I thanks to any answer

Comment: thank you for editing @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns the score for each word:

```
SELECT ek.ID as ID, COUNT(*) as Pscore
FROM englishkeyword ek, brand
WHERE (brand.text LIKE CONCAT('%', ek.word, '%'))
GROUP BY ek.ID
```

Then you can use this query to [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) the score.

```
INSERT INTO englishkeywordmodel (ID, Pscore)
    SELECT ek.ID as ID, COUNT(*) as Pscore
    FROM englishkeyword ek, brand
    WHERE (brand.text LIKE CONCAT('%', ek.word, '%'))
    GROUP BY ek.ID
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE Pscore = VALUES(Pscore)
```

Comment: but it already exists data in 'word' column, so maybe I need to update. sorry for lack info

Comment: Yes, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = VALUES(score)` will handle that.

Comment: it seemed query from @John Bupit is correct, but I don't know why still not correct

Comment: I got the reason why this solution not answer my question just now, because very simple reason, that is I don't give Primary Key on ID! maybe this useful for others to create Primary Key on ID. And Thank you very Much for John Bupit!!!

Comment: Didn't see your latest update in time. But, yes, the duplicate values of ID in the screenshot indicates that it is not the primary key.